# My visual studio 2019 preview giving me this error when running a xamarin forms application. (Mono.Debugger.soft.VMNotSuspendedException)

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

when debugging the application it automatically pops up on my screen.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7Xrh.png

Comment: Okay reinstall VS?

Comment: Please open your VS installer, click the repair selection, if it worked.